# Is there a way to stream certain sounds through my mic?

Tags: audio, skype, microphone, input

So for example, if I wanted to stream music from youtube through my headset to the people in my skype call, is there any way I can do that?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Windows, change the audio input device in Skype to "Stereo Mix". This will pipe all audio output to audio input.